# How can I improve my dribbling skills and my ball control for soccer?

Tags: football, training

Please tell me some good skills to improve my ball control, whether it be in air or on ground, and my dribbling skills, as I'm a huge fan of this game.

Comment: Also related: [Tips on improving my football](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2062/tips-on-improving-my-football/3408#3408)

Answer (score -2):

I don’t play soccer, nor do I pay much attention to soccer.

However, focus on 3 general principles, you can build some really cool athletic skills. Including dribbling a soccer ball better.

First and foremost, Focus on your balance. Think about keeping your chin over your bellybutton — at all times.

Once your balance is perfect (test it by alternating standing on one foot), think about minimizing your movements completely. If youre working on ball control, position your body in a place where you only have to move the smallest part of your leg. This will help you maintain your balance more consistently.

Finally, move smoothly and rhythmically. Start slow with each movement. Make that consistently smooth. As you do so, start to layer in complexity. Once you can dribble the ball slowly and smoothly, you can speed up.

This is a way of deconstructing any skill into trainable parts: You can train your balance. You can train minimizing your movements. You can train smoothness and Rhythm....
But it takes discipline and patience.

With that discipline and patience, you will grow more quickly and effectively.

Good luck and get after it!